An approximate identity is a sequence convergences to the delta distribution
In GTM249, the writer definite an approximate identity(as $t \rightarrow 0$ ) is a family of $L^1(\mathbb(R)^n)$ functions $k_{t}$ with the following three properties:

There exist a constant $c>0$ such that $\Vert k_{t} \Vert_{L^1}$ for all $t > 0$.
$\int k_{t} dx = 1$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.
For any $t > 0$, we have $\int_{|x| \geq \epsilon} k_{t} dx \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Now, I see other place a better definition of approximate identity, that is a family of tempered distribution convergence to the delta distribution in tempered distribution space.
My question is how can we prove the two definition are consists?
